# Tightness of a uniformly bounded sequence of functions integrated with respect to a semimartingale

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, limits-and-convergence, limit-theorems

I am reading [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1048516529) by Jacod, Jakubowski and Mémin. In the proof of Theorem 1.3 the authors define, for each $n\geq1$ the function $\phi_n$ by

$\quad\phi_n(s)=i+1-ns,\quad\text{if } \frac{i}{n}<s\leq\frac{i+1}{n},\quad\phi_n(0)=0$.

Then, for an arbitrary semimartingale $X$, they claim that the sequence of semimartingales $(\tilde{Y}'^n(X))_{n\geq1}$ is tight (in the Skorokhod J1-topology), where

$\quad\tilde{Y}'^n(X)_t=\int_0^t \phi_n(s)\,dX_s$.

They support this claim with a reference to Theorem VI.5.10 in Jacod & Shiryaev (1987).

Can anyone help me understand how this theorem is applied to get the desired tightness? Condition (i) is clearly satisfied (since $\tilde{Y}'^n_0=0$) but I have trouble verifying the remaining conditions. My only idea so far is to somehow use the fact that $|\phi_n(s)|\leq1$ for all $n\geq1,s\geq0$.

Comment: Can you state Theorem VI.5.10 in Jacod & Shiryaev? For those who do not have the book.

Comment: I see your point but unfortunately this is not straightforward. The total formulation of the theorem takes up around two pages (there are several conditions of which at least one must be satisfied) and it uses fairly complicated notation introduced earlier in the book.